# HTML Email Responsive Table Arrangment

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

I am trying to make a group of tables show up on mobile like it does on desktop.

This is what I am trying to do, but I can't figure it out:

[image: Problem & what I am looking for]

Here is my code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  }
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
img,a img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
table {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}
p,a,li,td,blockquote {
  mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
}
a[href^=tel],
a[href^=sms] {
  color: inherit;
  cursor: default;
  text-decoration: none;
}p,a,li,td,body,table,blockquote {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font {
  line-height: 100%;
}
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
  color: inherit !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit !important;
  font-weight: inherit !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
}
#bodyCell {
  padding: 10px;
}
.templateContainer {
  max-width: 600px !important;
}
a.mcnButton {
  display: block;
}
.mcnImage {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.mcnTextContent {
  word-break: break-word;
}
.mcnTextContent img {
  height: auto !important;
}
.mcnDividerBlock {
  table-layout: fixed !important;
}
.hero-header {
  font-size: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #658DA5;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 1px white, -2px -1px 0 #dcd388, -2px 1px 4px lightgray;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero-header {
    padding: 0 18px;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}
body,#bodyTable {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#bodyCell {
  border-top: 0;
}
.templateContainer {
  border: 0;
}
#templatePreheader {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #656565;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
}
#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent a,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #656565;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#templateHeader {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #202020;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
}
#templateHeader .mcnTextContent a,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #2BAADF;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#templateBody {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #202020;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
}
#templateBody .mcnTextContent a,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #2BAADF;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#templateUpperColumns {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
#templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent,#templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #202020;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
}
#templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent a,#templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #2BAADF;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#templateLowerColumns {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EAEAEA;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
#templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent,#templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #202020;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
}
#templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent a,#templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #2BAADF;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#templateFooter {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
#templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p {
  color: #656565;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: center;
}
#templateFooter .mcnTextContent a,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p a {
  color: #656565;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .templateContainer {
    width: 600px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #bodyCell {
    padding-top: 10px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .columnWrapper {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImage {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnCaptionTopContent,.mcnCaptionBottomContent,.mcnTextContentContainer,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer,.mcnImageGroupContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightTextContentContainer {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer {
    min-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageGroupContent {
    padding: 9px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter .mcnTextContent,
  .mcnCaptionRightContentOuter .mcnTextContent {
    padding-top: 9px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageCardTopImageContent,
  .mcnCaptionBlockInner .mcnCaptionTopContent:last-child .mcnTextContent {
    padding-top: 18px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageCardBottomImageContent {
    padding-bottom: 9px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageGroupBlockInner {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageGroupBlockOuter {
    padding-top: 9px !important;
    padding-bottom: 9px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnTextContent,
  .mcnBoxedTextContentColumn {
    padding-right: 18px !important;
    padding-left: 18px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnImageCardLeftImageContent,
  .mcnImageCardRightImageContent {
    padding-right: 18px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 18px !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcpreview-image-uploader {
    display: none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 22px !important;
    line-height: 125% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h2 {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    line-height: 125% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h3 {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    line-height: 125% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent,
  .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templatePreheader {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,
  #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templateHeader .mcnTextContent,
  #templateHeader .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templateBody .mcnTextContent,
  #templateBody .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent,
  #templateUpperColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent,
  #templateLowerColumns .columnContainer .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #templateFooter .mcnTextContent,
  #templateFooter .mcnTextContent p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    line-height: 150% !important;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
  <center>
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 10px;width: 100%;">

          <span width="100%">
                            
                            </span>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templateUpperColumns" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
             <tr>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
              <span width="100%">  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
             <tr>
              <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                 <tr>
                  <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                   <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                     <tr>
                      <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;">
                                                                            <a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=3950" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                                                            <img align="center" alt="Andover Tasting Calendar" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/a6c43d95-afba-46f1-9f35-bee25d2039cc.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="mcnImage"></a>

                      </td>
                         </tr>
                         </tbody>
    </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </td>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
             <tr>
              <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                 <tr>
                  <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">


                   <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                     <tr>
                      <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;"><a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=3962" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                                                            <img align="center" alt="Blaine Tasting Calendar" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/eb21b0ff-102c-4cae-b0cb-ecec8c2ecd32.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="mcnImage"></a>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                   </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
                                    
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </td>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
             <tr>
              <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                 <tr>
                  <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                   <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                     <tr>
                      <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;"><a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=5303" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                                                            <img align="center" alt="Cottage Grove Tasting Calendar" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/ebc7f7d0-1448-49cb-adb5-917844b27af3.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="mcnImage"></a>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                   </table>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody>
               </table>
              </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </td>
             </tr>
             </table>
             <![endif]-->
           </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" id="templateUpperColumns" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="width:600px;">
             <tr>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;">
                                    <a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=5303" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                      <img align="center" alt="Ramsey Tasting Calendar" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/c042ffa4-ffed-4ef6-a8f3-331ab96ac218.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                      class="mcnImage">
                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </td>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">


                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;">
                                    <a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=3953" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                      <img align="center" alt="St. Louis Park Events" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/fb85e468-a3fd-429e-b782-d0cd47134f1d.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                      class="mcnImage">
                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
             </td>
             <td align="center" valign="top" width="200" style="width:200px;">
             <![endif]-->
              <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" class="columnWrapper" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" class="columnContainer" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                      <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionBottomContent" width="false" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="mcnImage" valign="top" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;vertical-align: bottom;">
                                    <a href="http://toptenliquors.com/events?tribe_venues%5B%5D=3955" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
                                      <img align="center" alt="Woodbury Tasting Calendar" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/aff9f1b0278f339e6007bae6f/images/08bdf90b-f6a0-413e-94de-45183f0d90ec.png" style="max-width: 180px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                                      class="mcnImage">
                                    </a>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: I don't have time for a detailed analysis, but what jumps out at me is that you have a bunch of "ghost" code to force desktop behavior on Outlook. If you want to force desktop behavior everywhere, you need to remove the MSO conditional code and let the HTML rule everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your example above contains hybrid and responsive code to make the email change layouts from desktop to mobile. Sounds like you want to remove that.

---

Remove the following code:

**Responsive Classes**: Remove instances of `class="mcnImage"` from and `<td>` or `<img>` tag that you don't want to be full width on mobile.

**Ghost Table Markup for Outlook**: remove instances of `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` and `<![endif]-->`, including what's inside those two tags.

---

Once you remove the code that makes this part of the email responsive, your layout should go back to the desktop view even on small screens.